# Setting up Flutter in terminal yields a command not found message

Tags: macos, flutter

I'm trying to setup Flutter on my Mac but when I use the terminal to check the version I keep getting the message "zsh: command not found: flutter"

The steps that I've done to set it up are:

1. In a terminal window type vim ./zshrc
2. Paste the export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"
   code (changing the brackets to the actual file path)
3. :wq!
4. Testing the version by typing flutter --version

Is there something I'm missing, or something I'm not doing right?

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH step should likely be:

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin"
```

Note that the directory you want to add to your path is `bin`, not `flutter/bin`, relative to the Flutter git directory.

The [install instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux) for macOS and Linux specify the steps as:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
$ export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

Note that the git clone step creates a `flutter` directory within your current directory, so the path to add is `flutter/bin` relative to `pwd` (the current directory).

Comment: Actually -- it looks like our [Update your path](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path) instructions contain a bug! Thanks for spotting this. I'll get this patched up!

Comment: Patch to fix this is up at https://github.com/flutter/website/pull/5520

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with an editor nano or vim which will return a text editor terminal there you can edit path and save,eg

> nano .bash_profile

```
nano .bashrc
```